# Acumatica PXDefault or custom field default

Tags: asp.net, acumatica

I am new to Acumatica and trying to learn development. I do not understand how to default a value to a custom column.

Task is to create a new custom field and then when a line item is added to a Purchase Order, that field is populated automatically from the items attributes. I have experience in Odoo and Netsuite, and comparable functionality is related field or sourced field.

I see how to create a custom field to a screen using a customization project and layout editor, however I do not understand the proper procedure to have this field populated automatically. I have been told to use PXdefault, but I do not understand from reading the documentation how this is done.

Comment: You add PXDefault to your DAC field (property). You can look at other standard Acumatica DACs for examples or search the source for usages of PXDefault

Comment: Thank for you the response, but you did not answer the question or provide any code used to solve the problem.

Comment: I didn't have time for a full answer but more pointer in a direction. Did you review the default values help section: https://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(1))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=59a784a5-7663-4031-ab15-594c2ec1c027 and PXDefaultAttribute help sction:https://help.acumatica.com/(W(2))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=96b4e224-d0d2-e2d8-671e-9ba2ed73c21b Also the online training T100-300 courses should also help answer these questions. I would say if not at least looked into T100 it will save you a lot of time doing this first.